# javascript/css - prevent copy of text in span

Tags: javascript, css

Consider the following html:

```
<p class="chorus show-chords">
<span class="chord">ré69</span>Estava à toa na vida <span class="chord">lá7</span><br>
O meu amor me chamou <span class="chord">Fá#m7</span><br>
Pra ver a ban<span class="chord">si7</span>da passar<span class="chord">mi7(9)</span><br>
Cantando coi<span class="chord">lá7</span>sas de amor.
</p>
```

This is the first verse of a song (A Banda - Chico Buarque) with guitar chords. With my css it looks like this:

[image: html output example]

However, If I select the text and do Ctrl+C when I paste it in Word I get:

[image: example of copypaste to word]

Now I understand that I shouldn't expect to get the same as in the HTML, so I would like to simply throw away the chords when copying. My hope was to have something in the `<span>` definition that would prevent the text of the chord from being copied, so I turned to `oncopy=""` but this didn't work. To clarify, I was hoping that doing a Copy-paste would yield this:

[image: result without chords]

I tried preventing the selection by adding the following code to the `p.show-chords span` definition:

```
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
```

And while this made the text of the chords unselectable, it didn't prevent the chords to be copied over.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/d52xjqca/

Comment: you probably are looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027575/make-text-unselectable-and-uncopyable-webkit-while-surrounded-by-copyable-text

Comment: You are right, it is the exact same question!

Comment: well hope it helps

Comment: The answer solution works! https://jsfiddle.net/v8ryxunc/1/